# "For in" loop doesn't iterate over screen object in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This works in all browsers:

```
for (var i in navigator) {
    console.log(i, ':', navigator[i]);
}
```

But this doesn't work in IE 6 or 7: (loops zero times)

```
for (var i in screen) {
    console.log(i, ':', screen[i]);
}
```

What's different about the `screen` object?
And more importantly, how would I go about looping through it in IE?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Atepq/

Comment: This is a legitimate question, why are people downvoting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run tests, IE9 lets you get all the properties off the screen object with:

```
for (var prop in screen) {
    console.log(prop);
}
```

But, it won't let you access some of the properties to get their value.  When you do so, it stops JS execution.  It doesn't even throw an exception that you can catch.

Yes, this is brain dead, but it's not out of character with things that IE does, even in IE9.

If you really need to do this, you could one at a time figure out which properties IE doesn't work with and code to test for those and avoid them.  It might have to be updated from version to version, but it could get you going for whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

What's different is that **it's different...**

MDN points out that `screen` is not actually part of any spec...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen#Specification

Comment: Still, it's not really an excuse for the IE team of old to expose JS objects that are not JS objects when you try using them. Not a new complaint, I know, but I just keep getting surprised at how everything seems to be an exception in old IE.

Comment: So is there any way of looping through it? `.toString()` simply gives '[object]' in IE 6-7 (as opposed to `{}` being [object Object] and `navigator` being [object Navigator]. So what on earth is this object?